# Printing Active Child Form

Tags: vb.net, printing

I am new to VB and today I programmed my first form that uses parent and child forms. The assignment asks to "print the active child form" and I am a little stuck. So far this semester printing has not really been a big part of the assignments and I can't seem to find much in the book.

The way the assignment is coded is in the parent form there is a menu strip and I created a print click event in the menu. I guess I'm unsure where to start to make this be able to print just the active child form. My extent of printing my forms has been been dropping a printform from the VB powerpacks and then coding the form to print to preview.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Any hint would be huge so I know at least what to look for in the book. This is for homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. Here is a snipped of the code I used. I ended up keeping my printform from the powerpack I just was hung up on how to tell the program to find the active form.

Here is the code I used.

```
Private Sub PrintToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintToolStripMenuItem.Click, PrintToolStripButton.Click

    If Me.ActiveMdiChild Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If

    PrintForm1.Form = Me.ActiveMdiChild
    PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview

    PrintForm1.Print()
End Sub
```

Comment: @JeremyThompson I changed my answer.